# Why is $\|f-s_n(f)\|_2=\inf_{T\in\mathcal{T}_n}\|f-T\|_2$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I am working through some examples in my book in the section on Fourier Series.

Why is $\|f-s_n(f)\|_2=\inf_{T\in\mathcal{T}_n}\|f-T\|_2$?

where $f$ is a continuous $2\pi$ periodic function, $T$ is some trig. polynomial, and $s_n(f)$ is a trig. polynomial of degree at most $n$, $\mathcal{T}_n$ is the space of all trig. polynomials of degree $n$

Thoughts:

Writing this out, I get:

$$\left(\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f-s_n(f))^2\right)^{1/2}=\inf_{T\in\mathcal{T_n}}\left(\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f-T)^2\right)^{1/2}$$

I understand that both $s_n(f)$ and $T$ are both trig. polynomials of degree at most $n$, but I'm not seeing why this means that the two integrals are necessarily equal.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you are missing squares inside the integrals.

Comment: Here $s_n(f)$ should be the truncated Fourier series of $f$. I think this is related to Bessel's inequality

Comment: $s_n(f)$ is the best approximation for all $T \in \mathbb{T}_n$, since $s_n(f)$ is the orthogonal projector. We want that $\forall g \in T_n$, $\langle f-s_n(f), g \rangle = 0$. In this case, $s_n(f)$ would the best approximation for $f$. The element $s_n(f)$ can then be expressed as a linear combination of elements of $\{1, \cos x, \dots, \cos nx, \sin nx\} = T_n$, thus being the orthogonal projector. Google might help you with keywords "best approximation" and "orthogonal projection".

Comment: See maybe [Example 4.3.2 here](http://www-solar.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~clare/Lectures/num-analysis/Numan_chap4.pdf)